# How hello world app works in background in java

Tags: java, background, jvm

I want to know what happens in background when I run a simple java hello world application without any extra initial parameters.

For example in background how java call windows functions like drawing a simple window:

```
public  class example
{  
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
           System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
}
```

or

```
public  class example2 extends Jframe
{  
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
           new example2().setvisible(true);
        }
}
```

Comment: huh?wha?immaconfused,bro. o_O

Comment: Are you asking at a software, or hardware level?

Comment: I've  tried to run this simple code on linux no x11 installed and it is not worked.For example how java lookandfeel classes able to decorate window frames?This shows Operating System provides some functions for hooking drawing process.What happens if one systems provides any function and other does'nt? How java handle this implementation differances. I am wondering  all the phases from java classLoader startup to window appears.(Just software layer)

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/overview/intro.html

Java is intended to be platform independent.  It's not using native windows calls, at least not directly.

Comment: i read the intro thanks but it doesnt mention about barkground processes this article talk about swing utilities generally

Answer (score 1):

> How java call windows functions like drawing a simple window?

I guess you are asking about [Java Native Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).

Comment: no i dont ask about jni it is about java interpreter ,how jvm executes bytecode  independent platform

Comment: Do you need exact byte-code instruction? When Java needs to call some operation system API it uses JNI bridge to forward call to corresponding native library.

Comment: hıım ok it is exactly what i need .so jvm uses jni in background to comunicate OS libraries  so how can i see bytecode instructions ? it is possible while compiling

Comment: You can try to create simple JNI script your self and decompile it. Or ask another question on SO. Something like "How java do JNI calls on bytecode level?". Looks like this question is inactive now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how the JVM interacts with the underlying operating system, [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30422/How-the-Java-Virtual-Machine-JVM-Works) gives a general, platform-independent overview of its architecture.

I think you may be particularly interested in the section headed "The Byte Code Instruction Set", which states that when executing the line:

```
System.out.println("Hello world!");
```

> At compile time, the Java compiler converts the single-line print statement to the following byte code:

```
0 getstatic #6 <Field java.lang.System.out Ljava/io/PrintStream;>
3 ldc #1 <String "Hello world!"> 
5 invokevirtual #7 <Method java.io.PrintStream.println(Ljava/lang/String;)V> 
8 return
```

It may also be worth noting that JDK includes a tool that you can use to examine byte code, called the **class file disassembler**. You can make use of this tool using the **javap** command in your terminal of choice.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your first example of code only prints "Hello World!" into a terminal.
As for calling a window, the OS handles it. In case you haven't noticed there is a difference between a window on OSX and one on Windows.